# How to return nodes according to the percentage of search matches In neo4j fulltext search?

Tags: neo4j, full-text-search, cypher

I am using neo4j auto index as fulltext index. I have a user nodes which have a property 'fullName' now I want to perform search on the user nodes.
e.g Say I have 4 user with fullName as follows: Abc Jay, Jay Singh, Ajay Kumar, John Doe. So I want when the user search for jay then the result should be in order like this :

- Jay Singh,
- Ajay Kumar,
- Abc Jay

I have written this query :

```
START u=node:node_auto_index("fullName:*jay*") MATCH (u:User) 
return distinct {firstName : u.firstName , lastName : u.lastName, fullName : u.fullName, profilePicture : u.profilePicture, id : u.id} as user
```

This query giving me same users as result but in some random order not in the order which I want. Anyone who can help me to achieve this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So a quick way of finding the position would be to use split.

```
START u=node:node_auto_index("fullName:*jay*") 
MATCH (u:User) 
WITH distinct u
RETURN {firstName : u.firstName , lastName : u.lastName, fullName : u.fullName, profilePicture : u.profilePicture, id : u.id} as user
ORDER BY length(split(toLower(u.fullName,"jay")[0]);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it solved my problem. Just a silly mistake you need to place closing bracket ')' after u.fullName. Also what would happen if search keyword consist of more than one word.